# Test varying number of inequalities

Tags: computational-geometry, inequalities

I want to test a varying number of inequalities

```
test = 
  {{0, 0, 0}, {-0.0312454, 0.19754, 0.00135768}, 
   {0.127356, 0.295848, -0.070622}, {0.162562, 0.0589901, -0.100469}, 
   {-0.0872373, 0.172834, -0.05018}, {0.0875857, -0.100076, -0.19574}, 
   {0.0251443, -0.0773862, -0.0502886}, {0.1103, 0.11144, -0.14614}};
tolerance = 2*radius*0.01;

FirstCase[
  Nearest[
    MeshCoordinates[
      DiscretizeGraphics[Sphere[test[[3]], 2*radius]]], 
      test[[4]], 
      {100, radius}], (* create a list of points *)
  _?(2*radius <= EuclideanDistance[test[[7]], #] < 2*radius + tolerance &)]
```

I want to be able to vary the number of distances I test against.

`_?(2*radius <= EuclideanDistance[test[[7]], #] < 2*radius + tolerance &)]`

Say, I have 5 points and want to run the inequality to however many points are within a certain range. I can use `&&` to add another condition, but I want to vary it based on each case.

I'm thinking that if I calculate the distances to both/all and then run the inequality over each element of each list ... but I cant quite see it yet or would this be a wrong method?

Comment: I think you want `Select[]` instead: `SelectFirst[Nearest[MeshCoordinates[DiscretizeGraphics[Sphere[test[[3]], 2 radius]]], test[[4]], {100, radius}], Between[EuclideanDistance[test[[7]], #], {2 radius, 2 radius + tolerance}] &]`

Comment: for `tlist = test[[{1,5, 7, 9}]]`, say, you can use  the function `patterntest = LessEqual[ 2*radius, ## & @@ MinMax[Function[{t}, EuclideanDistance[t, #]] /@ tlist],  2*radius + tolerance] &` as the  pattern test  ( `_?patterntest`) in `FirstCases` or as the second argument of `SelectFirst`.

Comment: @J.M. Thanks! Is `Select[]` generally quicker than `Cases[]` ? The between really seems to tidy the second part up but there's still an issue of applying it for multiple distances.

Comment: They're about the same, but `Select[]` is more natural to use when you're filtering by an *expression test*, while `Cases[]` is more intended for filtering by *pattern matching*. I'm hazy on what you mean by "multiple distances"; what would vary in the code I gave in my comment?

Comment: @kglr Thanks, so `t` would be the number of points I test the distance to? but why the use of MinMax?

Comment: @J.M. Apologies, I want to be able to see if the point from `test` satisfies the distance to 1 or more points. Say I two points equidistant and a grouping of random points above, I want to select a point that is a distance from both satisfying the inequality *edit but the number of points can vary?

Comment: @AwkwardPanda, I may have misunderstood  the role of "5 points" but I thought  you meant  something like `_?(And[2*radius <= EuclideanDistance[test[[1]], #] < 2*radius + tolerance, 2*radius <= EuclideanDistance[test[[5]], #] < 2*radius + tolerance,2*radius <= EuclideanDistance[test[[7]], #] < 2*radius + tolerance,2*radius <= EuclideanDistance[test[[9]], #] < 2*radius + tolerance] &)]`  if this is a correct interpretation of your question then the form using `MinMax` is equivalent to this (since all elements of `testlist`  >= `2 radius` iff    `2 radius <= Min[testlist]` ...

Comment: ... and all elements of `testlist` being less than or equal to  `2 radius + tolerance` is equivalent to `Max[testlist]<=2 radius + tolearance`.)

Comment: OK... so in the code in my first snippet, I'm getting at most 100 points nearest to `test[[4]]`, and then picking out those that satisfy your brackets involving the point `test[[7]]`. What would change in the "many points" case, `test[[7]]` or `test[[4]]`?

Comment: @J.M. Feel like the not so popular 4th character Dorothy didn't pick up because they couldn't explain what they wanted from the wizard.. 

In that example, 100 points around `[[4]]` which has a distance to `[[7]]` that satisfies the inequality, but if `[[7]]={1,2,..n}` is more than one point which out of the 100 satisfies the condition to all n points?

Comment: Ah, so instead of just `test[[7]]`, you have a bunch of points? It would go something like `SelectFirst[Nearest[MeshCoordinates[DiscretizeGraphics[Sphere[test[[3]], 2 radius]]], test[[4]], {100, radius}], Apply[And, Table[Between[EuclideanDistance[pt, #], {2 radius, 2 radius + tolerance}], {pt, myPoints}]] &]` where `myPoints` is the cluster of points that takes the place of `test[[7]]`.

Comment: @J.M. Awesome!!! Thanks

I was playing around and got this 
`In[147]:= b={{1,1,1},{0,0,0}}
n=2;
y1=Table[{RandomInteger[10],RandomInteger[10],RandomInteger[10]},5]

Table[Outer[EuclideanDistance,{b[[k]]},y1,1],{k,1,n}]
Out[147]= {{1,1,1},{0,0,0}}
Out[149]= {{3,0,5},{8,3,5},{5,2,3},{2,3,5},{3,10,1}}
Out[150]= {{{Sqrt[21],Sqrt[69],Sqrt[21],Sqrt[21],Sqrt[85]}},{{Sqrt[34],7 Sqrt[2],Sqrt[38],Sqrt[38],Sqrt[110]}}}`
Is your method better? it seems a lot smoother